# I got error Mail failure - rejected by local scanning code in Opencart

Tags: email, opencart, cpanel

I got below error in mail
The FROM field must be the same as the user you are doing
SMTP / FROM address authentication must match your authenticated email
user

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty self explanatory. You're authenticating with an email address and you try to send the email from another email address. Some server have such protection. So be sure that the FROM address matches the actual email address you use to authenticate via SMTP.